# Second function start before first is finished, Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop outside of these two big `if´s`. My problem seems to be that the second function seems to fire off with a short delay. Should´t First function be done and then second will run?

Can´t figure the problem out why second start before first one is finished. When second function fires aswell it will increase the orignal number from zero to 60.

```
if(activeSlideBoolean && activeSlide < i){
    step = 0;
    div[activeSlide].className = 'slide left';

    animateHalfLeft(activeSlide);

    function animateHalfLeft(activeSlide){
        if(step < -60){
            return; 
        }

        div[activeSlide].style.left = step+'em';
        step -= 6;


        setTimeout (function(){ animateHalfLeft(activeSlide);},100);


    }

    activeSlideBoolean = false;

}
if((activeSlideBoolean === false) && (RestOfSlides)){
    step = 60;
    animateTotalLeft(RestOfSlides);

    function animateTotalLeft(RestOfSlides){
        f(step < -60){
            return; 
        }

        div[RestOfSlides].style.left = step+'em';
        step -= 6;
        setTimeout (function(){ animateTotalLeft(RestOfSlides);},100);  

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring your functions inside a condition? And what does `f(step < -60)` meaan?

Comment: I have dynamic variables outside the condition and i don´t know how to get them in a fucntion outside the main function(div[1],div[2]) etc

Comment: "dynamic variables"? Aren't they always dynamic? You maybe should read something about parameters & declaring functions

Comment: Yes, they are not showing in here becouse they aren´t the problem i suppose but rather how to stop the second function from firing before first one is done

Comment: *"When second function fires aswell it will increase the orignal number from zero to 60."* No it doesn't. `step` is set to `60` *immediately* in the second `if` statement. And that `if` statement is executed *before*  `animateHalfLeft` is called a second time, since you are using `setTimeout`.

Comment: Should´t animateHalfLeft complete before activeSlideBoolean is set to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function animateHalfLeft and animateTotalLeft are exactly the same except for one thing the argument activeSlide and RestOfSlides.

I suggest first to create a separate function :

```
function animateToLeft(whatToSlide){
        if(step < -60){
            return; 
        }

        div[whatToSlide].style.left = step+'em';
        step -= 6;
        setTimeout (function(){ animateToLeft(whatToSlide);},100);  

    }
}
```

But the function is still finishing before setTimeout ends (or even starts).

Javascript is a functional language. Use it :

```
function animateToLeft(whatToSlide, step, callback){
        if(step < -60){
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback();
            }
            return; 
        }

        div[whatToSlide].style.left = step+'em';
        step -= 6;
        setTimeout (function(){ 
            animateToLeft(whatToSlide , step, callback);
        },100);  
    }
}

if(activeSlideBoolean && activeSlide < i){
    var isStarted = false;
    animateToLeft(activeSlide, 0, function() {
        if (isStarted) {
            return;
        }
        isStarted = true;

        if (RestOfSlides) {
            animateToLeft(RestOfSlides, 60, null);
            // Finishing order 3
        }
    }); 
    // Finishing order 1
}

if(activeSlideBoolean === false && RestOfSlides){
    animateToLeft(RestOfSlides, 60, null);
    // finishing order 2
}
```

I don't know if it works for you (don't copy/paste idiotly) but for me, it's a good start.